# Add two number in c strange behaviour

Tags: c, addition

I was reading this [Why is the sum of two large integers a negative number in the C language?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-sum-of-two-large-integers-a-negative-number-in-the-C-language). Then I tried the following code:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int x,y,s;
    x = 4294967295;
    y = 4294967295;
    s = x+y;
    printf("%u",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output : `4294967294`

1 ) How does it calculate sum (s)? I am a bit confused by the explanation given in the link.

When I increase the values of `x` and `y` to the extent which is beyond the range of `unsigned int` the result always seems to be in range of unsigned int. In fact it seems like the result keeps decreasing. 
It does give the following error.

> sample.c:7:9: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

2 ) Can I brute force this program so that whenever value of `x` and `y` exceeds unsigned int range program throws an error.

Comment: What exactly were you expecting as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard has well defined behavior for unsigned integer overflow.  When this happens, the mathematical result is truncated modulo the maximum allowable value + 1.  In layman's terms, this means that the values wrap around.

In the case of adding 4294967295 and 4294967295, this wraparound behavior results in 4294967294.

Throwing an error would be in violation of the standard.

Comment: You can "brute force" the program by checking for overflow before doing any assignments to the unsigned int though.

Comment: @CoreyLakey Why? C has a standard header `limits.h` defining the minimum and maximum values for standard types.

Comment: I don't know why he would do it lol @Eugene Sh. but he asked if he could and he can.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 ) How does it calculate sum (s)?

See [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734859/2410359) good answer.

> 2 ) Can I brute force this program so that whenever value of x and y exceeds unsigned int range program throws an error.

Code could detect the mathematical overflow easily with `unsigned` math.  Math overflow occurs if sum is less than an operand of the addition.  Testing against only one of `x` or `y` is sufficient.

```
unsigned int x,y,s;
x = 4294967295;
y = 4294967295;
s = x+y;
printf("%u\n",s);
if (s < x) puts("Math overflow");
// or 
if (s < y) puts("Math overflow");
return 0;
```

For *signed* `int` tests, see [Test if arithmetic operation will cause undefined behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485)

Answer (score 0):

In you case `unsigned int` is 32 bits, 4294967295 + 4294967295 == 8589934590 which has a ***33*** bit binary value:

```
1 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
^
Carry bit
```

The carry bit is lost because the representation has only 32 bits, and the resulting value:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 = 4294967294 decimal
```

You must either detect an overflow before it happens to store the result in a larger type and test its value.

```
if( UINT_MAX - x < y )
{
    puts("Math overflow") ;
}
else
{
    s = x + y ;
    printf( "%u\n", s ) ;
}
```

Or:

```
unsigned long long s = x + y ;
if( s > UINT_MAX )
{
    puts("Math overflow") ;
}
else
{
    printf( "%u\n", (unsigned int)s ) ;
}
```

Comment: The second overflow detection code assumes `unsigned long long` is longer than `unsigned int`, so it's not as good as the first.

Comment: A prior test or wider math are 2 good options answered here.  For unsigned integer math, unlike signed integer math, the overflow can also be detected after the operation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [kias.dyndns.org](http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/13.html):

> Most modern computers store memory in units of 8 bits, called a "byte"
>   (also called an "octet"). Arithmetic in such computers can be done in
>   bytes, but is more often done in larger units called "(short)
>   integers" (16 bits), "long integers" (32 bits) or "double integers"
>   (64 bits). Short integers can be used to store numbers between 0 and
>   2<sup>16</sup> - 1, or 65,535. **Long integers can be used to store numbers between
>   0 and 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, or 4,294,967,295.** and double integers can be used to
>   store numbers between 0 and 2<sup>64</sup> - 1, or 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.
>   (Check these!)

[...]

> When a computer performs an unsigned integer arithmetic operation,
>    there are three possible problems which can occur:
>
> - **if the result is too large to fit into the number of bits assigned to
>     it, an "overflow" is said to have occurred.** For example if the result
>     of an operation using 16 bit integers is larger than 65,535, an
>     overflow results.
> - in the division of two integers, if the result is not itself an
>     integer, a "truncation" is said to have occurred: 10 divided by 3 is
>     truncated to 3, and the extra 1/3 is lost. This is not a problem, of
>     course, if the programmer's intention was to ignore the remainder!
> - any division by zero is an error, since division by zero is not
>     possible in the context of arithmetic.

[Original emphasis removed; emphasis added.]

Comment: Do note that the type names and descriptions in your quoted materials are not congruent to C's definitions of its standard built-in integer types.  Also note that this doesn't actually answer the question.